# Sass::SyntaxError: Invalid CSS after "...orm-group::not(": expected pseudo_expr, was ":first-child)"

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, heroku

I got the following error while pushing the code to Heroku. This is the issue with '[freelancer](http://startbootstrap.com/template-overviews/freelancer/)' template.

**Sass::SyntaxError: Invalid CSS after "...orm-group::not(": expected pseudo_expr, was ":first-child)"** error is seen with the following code while pre-compiling the Assets in production mode.

```
.floating-label-form-group::not(:first-child) {
    padding-left: 14px;
    border-left: 1px solid #eee;
}
```

Answer (score 12):

After placing quotes around the :first-child solved my problem

```
.floating-label-form-group::not(':first-child') {
    padding-left: 14px;
    border-left: 1px solid #eee;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! it work's - only thing I have the same issue at "less/freelancer.less" , updates in both files.